# odbc syntax to update

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc

```
string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=new_db;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=password;" + "OPTION=3";

OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);

OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE awm_create SET referral_email=?' WHERE email=? " , MyConnection);

//cmd.Parameters.Add("@tb_refemail", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = tb_refemail.Text.Trim();
//cmd.Parameters.Add("@tb_email", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = tb_email.Text.Trim();

MyConnection.Open();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How to provide the referral_email and email using forms?

Do the comment code works in any way??

Please correct the above code

Comment: Have you tried the code you posted?  What doesn't work?

Comment: yeah...! code works when I give values instead of "?" but I do need to give input using forms not using code.

Comment: Do you get an error, or just no results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quote in your command text:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE awm_create 
   SET referral_email=? WHERE email=?" , MyConnection);
```

Comment: Nope.! I mean how to pass ? values using forms?