# ODBC update using ASP.NET forms

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc

How do I pass karthik@domain.com and kars@domain.com using ASP.NET forms (textbox) ?

```
string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=new_db;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=password;" + "OPTION=3";

OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);

OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE awm_create SET referral_email='karthik@domain.com' WHERE email='kars@domain.com'" , MyConnection);

MyConnection.Open();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [odbc syntax to update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173458/odbc-syntax-to-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I got the answer that is...

```
string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=new_db;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=password;" + "OPTION=3";

OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
           OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE awm_create SET referral_email=? WHERE email=?" , MyConnection);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@tb_refemail", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = tb_refemail.Text.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@tb_email", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = lblemail.Text;

            MyConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add two asp.net textbox controls to the web form and upon postback (using the IsPostBack flag) you can pull the email address from the textboxes in the PageLoad event... i.e. something like:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if(Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      // add validation here for the text boxes if you need...
      string refEmail= txtReferralEmail.Text.Trim();
      string email = txtEmail.Text.Trim();

      //then you can do something like this:

      var sql = string.Format("UPDATE awm_create SET referral_email='{0}' WHERE email='{1}'", refEmail, email);

      OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql , MyConnection);
      try{
           MyConnection.Open();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }Catch(Exception e){
           // log your exception or whatever you need to do
      }
    }
}
```

Don't forget you'll need to add two text boxes to your aspx form with the names txtReferralEmail and txtEmail.

Comment: Say 'hi' to Little Bobby Tables for me.  ;-)

Comment: To supplement Forgotten Semicolon's reference, you may want to sanitize your data to prevent SQL injection attacks (+1 for the XKCD ref)